# systemd script doesn't run

Tags: systemd

I have this very simple `systemd`.

```
[Unit]
Description="Something"

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart nginx
```

When I try to run it, using `systemctl start my-script.service`, and I query it using `systemctl status my-script.service`, it shows status `Loaded`, and will do so for all eternity.

I have the feeling, the issue is that I want to use `systemctl` from within `systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl status` will reported "Loaded" for your service because it is indeed loaded into systemd at that point. I'm not sure what else you were expecting. I tried starting your service myself and it worked as expected, issuing a restart to the Nginx service:

```
$ journalctl | tail -10
Apr 27 12:39:28 myhost.com systemd[1]: Started "Something".
Apr 27 12:39:28 myhost.com systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 27 12:39:28 myhost.com systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Apr 27 12:39:28 myhost.com systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 27 12:39:28 myhost.com systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

If your systemd service file is not working as expected, please be more specific in your question.